# Smoothing Animation of Collapsible Panels Inside Listviews

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, animation

I have the following code to smooth animation on a collapsiblepanel, and it works splendidly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        smoothAnimation();
    }


    function smoothAnimation() {
        var collPanel = $find(("<%= CollapsiblePanelExtender.ClientID %>"));
        collPanel._animation._fps = 30;
        collPanel._animation._duration = 0.5;
    }

</script>
```

Now, I also have a listview, separate from the above panel, that has a collapsible panel extender inside each of its items.  I would like to apply that "smoothAnimation()" function to each of them, but I don't know how to do that, since databinding gives each item a unique ID.

Does anybody know how to approach this in javascript?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the OnItemCreated event, and use the following:

```
protected void ListItems_Created(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    CollapsiblePanelExtender cpe = (CollapsiblePanelExtender)e.Item.FindControl("collapsePanelID");
    cpe.Attributes.Add("onload", cpe.ClientID + "._animation._fps = 30;");
    cpe.Attributes.Add("onload", cpe.ClientID + "._animation._duration = 0.5;");

}
```

This code is untested but it's all you should need to get this working.

Comment: CollapsiblePanelExtender  does not have an Attributes Attribute